# Google Maps API - Twitter feed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, twitter

My website uses PHP, mySQL, Javascript and the Google Maps API. 
Each marker is a location (obviously!), and has information which is loaded into 2 DIVs on the page.
What I want to do is include a Twitter feed for each location, which are mostly nightclubs. I've created the entry for the locations, and the Twitter username can be printed on the page (as a test). Somehow, I need to successfully integrate the Timeline widget supplied by Twitter:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/" + twitter + " data-widget-id="255281308568272896">Tweets by @" + name + "</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

into my 2nd HTML variable:

```
var html2 = "<div class=loc-desc><h2>Description</h2>" + desc + "</div><div class=loc-wevents><h2>Weekly Events</h2>" + weeklydeals + "</div>";
```

For those familiar with the API and its variable placement, you'll notice that I've already laid the variable groundwork for the 2nd HTML variable. In this instance, 'twitter' is the Twitter username (stored without the @), and 'name' is the name of the location. 
(Just in case clarification was needed!)

This is what I attempted initially:

```
var html2 = "<div class=loc-desc><h2>Description</h2>" + desc + "</div><div class=loc-wevents><h2>Weekly Events</h2>" + weeklydeals + "</div><a class=twitter-timeline href=https://twitter.com/ + twitter + " data-widget-id=255281308568272896>Tweets by " + name + "</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,script,twitter-wjs);</script>";
```

The problem I'm having is that the Javasript throws a hissy-fit because of the semi-colons in the twitter function.

I did attempt to seperate the function from the block of code given to me by twitter, but it became very messy, and I think the widget may be in JSON, or at least something that reads different to Javascript.

Here's what I attempted:

```
function twitter(d,s,id){
var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(!d.getElementById(id)){
    js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

I then tried to attach the function to the bit in the 2nd HTML area, though I'm fairly sure this is not how it's supposed to be done:

```
var html2 = "<div class=loc-desc><h2>Description</h2>" + desc + "</div><div class=loc-wevents><h2>Weekly Events</h2>" + weeklydeals + "</div><a onload=twitter() class=twitter-timeline href=https://twitter.com/" + twitter + " data-widget-id=255281308568272896>Tweets by" + name + "(@" + twitter ")</a>";
```

What I'd like is for someone who has a deeper understanding of Javascript to point me in the right direction. From what I can understand, having the whole function in the HTML area won't work, due to the requirement for semi-colons, which throws errors in my console.

Any help would be fantastic, as always

Tristan